# vb.net WebBrowser links to Default Web Browser

Tags: vb.net, browser

is there a way to detect a person clicking a link inside WebBrowser1, and then i can do

```
Process.Start(TheURL)
```

And then return the action as false so it doesn't click the link in the webbrowser object and just the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
private void WebBrowser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
  {  
        e.Cancel = true; // Cancel the event to avoid default behavior
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Url.ToString()); // Open the link in the default browser
  }
```

EDIT:  Meh, I had a few minutes.  Here ya go again:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
  e.Cancel = True 'Cancel the event to avoid default behavior
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Url.ToString()) 'Open the link in the default browser
End Sub
```

Comment: Ick, sorry I didn't see the VB tag on the post.  If you need a translation I can make that happen, but most of that should copy over pretty painlessly.