# VB.NET WebBrowser control - how do you submit to default browser?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, submit, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser control in my VBForm.
It looks for a website on my site and displays it.

There are form submit buttons in that WebBrowser1.
I would like it to be so that when they click a button in the WebBrowser1 Web page it will open their own browser to submit the form

How do i do this?

(yes, it's my website. i can change the HTML on the server if that is needed. )

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562183/opening-default-web-browser

Comment: no. i'm looking to make a LINK in the VB browser control to open their browser to perform the submit. not for how to open their browser from a sub or function.

Comment: but if you can show me how to make the SUBMIT BUTTON in a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser call a sub that will then open their browser to submit the form, then i could use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is thanks to: [Opening default web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562183/opening-default-web-browser)
and: [vb.net WebBrowser links to Default Web Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253409/vb-net-webbrowser-links-to-default-web-browser)

and some trial and error. working result follows:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
    'added a match string - if Allow is inside the URL link, then the WebBrowser control is allowed to navigate to it. otherwise use their browser.
    dim Allow as string = "http://mysite.com"
    If InStr(e.Url.ToString(), Allow) = 0 Then
        ' I'm trying here to cancel the event so that the WebBrowser1 control doesn't go there.
        e.Cancel = True
        ' then start a new process with their default browser
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(getDefaultBrowser(), e.Url.ToString())
    End If
End Sub

Private Function getDefaultBrowser() As String
    Dim browser As String = String.Empty
    Dim key As RegistryKey = Nothing
    Try
        key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("HTTP\shell\open\command", False)

        'trim off quotes
        browser = key.GetValue(Nothing).ToString().ToLower().Replace("""", "")
        If Not browser.EndsWith("exe") Then
            'get rid of everything after the ".exe"
            browser = browser.Substring(0, browser.LastIndexOf(".exe") + 4)
        End If
    Finally
        If key IsNot Nothing Then
            key.Close()
        End If
    End Try
    Return browser
End Function
```

I never would of solved it if Martin Parkin didn't post up that duplicate warning.

also - had to change my links to METHOD = GET, the post headers don't always translate in this manner.